# @CrossOrigin only works when register one domain

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wanted to make an connection between frontend and backend so I used @CrossOrigin annotation Like below.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000, http://server ip:3000, http://backend.com:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class MemberController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberController.class);
    private MemberService ms;
    private Encryption encrypt;
    private S3FileUploadService sfu;

    @Autowired
    public MemberController(MemberService ms, Encryption encrypt,S3FileUploadService sfu) {
        this.ms = ms;
        this.encrypt = encrypt;
        this.sfu = sfu;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public FrontMember login(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String autho) {
        logger.info("Authorization : " + autho);

        String memberInform = encrypt.aesDecrypt(autho);
        String[] idPwd = memberInform.split("/");
        Member loginTry = new Member();
        loginTry.setEmail(idPwd[0]);
        loginTry.setPwd(encrypt.shaEncryption(idPwd[1]));
        Member authorizedUser = ms.login(loginTry);
        if(authorizedUser == null){
            logger.warn("No member info");
            return null;
        }else{
            logger.info("Member Get : "+authorizedUser.toString());
            String hashMemberNum = encrypt.aesEncrypt(Integer.toString(authorizedUser.getMemberNum()));
            String mgHash = encrypt.aesEncrypt(Integer.toString(authorizedUser.getMg()));
            FrontMember fm = new FrontMember(hashMemberNum, authorizedUser.getNickName(), authorizedUser.getPfUrl(),mgHash);
            logger.info("Login User : "+fm.toString());
            return fm;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work unless I only put one domain on origin like below.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

I want to put several domain at crossorigin.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html) of `CrossOrign`,we can found below description:
[image]

So the reason is that you have made a wrong invocation,if you need to allow multiple origins,**you need to use an array contains of string instead of single string**

In order to make your code work,you can try with below:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", "http://server ip:3000", "http://backend.com:3000"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/member")
public class MemberController {
}
```